# Resource identifier not provided for Angular SPA using Azure AD

Tags: angular, azure, openid-connect

I'm using the modified Visual Studio template from https://github.com/damienbod/dotnet-template-angular to build an Angular SPA using Asp.Net API with Azure AD logon. This uses https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client on the Angular side to talk to Azure.

I get the Micosoft logon as expected but after enter my user logon detail, it returns with error:

AADSTS500013 - Resourse identifier is not provided

I've seen this error in some other questions here but with different app setups that did not use the same Angular OIDC cliet. I'm not sure if this is the problem or am I missing something on the Azure app registration?

UPDATE
My Azure app is registered using the old version app registration so looks looks like this:

```
"oidc": {
    "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[....]/",
    "client_id": "[...]",
    "scope": "openid",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
}
```

Comment: I thought this forum was to help each other, not break people down?

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered your application in the Azure AD used to authenticate users? There you'll see an Application ID which must be provided for the ASP.NET application in the `appsettings.json` file, under the `clientId` node:

```
  "oidc": {
    "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/",
    "client_id": "d4d8dc5a-3e3b-4cf8-9ba5-eee9e27764a1",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "resource": "https://graph.windows.net",
    "prompt": "consent"
  }
```

Also make sure that you're including your Azure AD tenant's OIDC configuration in your Angular application as stated in the comments [app.module.ts](https://github.com/damienbod/dotnet-template-angular/blob/master/dotnet-angular-azure-ad-oidc/ClientApp/src/app/app.module.ts) of the dotnet-angular-azure-ad-oidc library's `loadConfig` function.

```js
export function loadConfig(oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService) {
  console.log('APP_INITIALIZER STARTING');
  // https://login.microsoftonline.com/damienbod.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
  // jwt keys: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
  // Azure AD does not support CORS, so you need to download the OIDC configuration, and use these from the application.
  // The jwt keys needs to be configured in the well-known-openid-configuration.json
  return () => oidcConfigService.load(`${window.location.origin}/api/config/configuration`);
  //return () => oidcConfigService.load_using_custom_stsServer('https://localhost:44347/well-known-openid-configuration.json');
}
```

This configuration is reachable at `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

Comment: Not sure what to do with the second part you mention? I have the loadConfig exactly as you show it exactly as from the original git repo. How do I configure this? Doesn't the .Net Core API controller, ../api/config/configuration, get the necessary configs from Azure?